# Get column names in its own column to render pie chart

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am writing a query in Kusto to parse heartbeat data from a sensor. This is what I've written:

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, healthycount:int, unhealthycount:int, origin:string)
[
    datetime(1910-06-11), 10, 1, 'origin',
    datetime(1910-05-11), 9, 2, 'origin'
]
| summarize latest = arg_max(timestamp, *) by origin
| project healthy = healthycount,
    unhealthy = unhealthycount
```

This outputs data like this:

```
+--------------+----------------+
|   healthy    |   unhealthy    |
+--------------+----------------+
|           10 |              1 |
+--------------+----------------+
```

However, I want to represent this data as a pie chart, but to do that I need the data in the following format:

```
+----------------+-------+
|      key       | value |
+----------------+-------+
| healthy        |    10 |
| unhealthy      |     1 |
+----------------+-------+
```

Is it possible to do this? What terminology am I looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, healthycount:int, unhealthycount:int, origin:string)
[
    datetime(1910-06-11), 10, 1, 'origin',
    datetime(1910-05-11), 9, 2, 'origin'
]
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by origin
| extend Pack = pack("healthycount", healthycount, "unhealthycount", unhealthycount)
| mv-expand kind=array Pack 
| project key = tostring(Pack[0]), value = toint(Pack[1])
```

Comment: This is awesome and will be very helpful in the future too, thanks!